# Not able to see TestNG in eclipse neon after installing

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I installed TestNG from eclipse marketplace successfully but not able to see TestNG in windows- preferences.i  have eclipse neon and latest jdk version java SE 8u121. Does any body know?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install TestNG in Eclipse either navigating to "Help -> Install New Software" or from "Eclipse Market Place"
2. Check whether TestNG successfully got installed or not:
   -In Eclipse Browse to: "Window -> Show View -> Other -> Java"
   -TestNG must be listed.
3. Add TestNG library from "Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Library -> Select TestNG -> Apply -> OK"
4. Create a simple Test Script as follows;

`package gmail;`

`import org.testng.annotations.Test;`

`public class gmailLoginTestNG {`

```
@Test
public void test1()
{
    System.out.println("Within Test 1");
}

@Test
public void test2()
{
    System.out.println("Within Test 2");
}

@Test
public void test3()
{
    System.out.println("Within Test 3");
}
```

`}`

5. Right Click & Run As "TestNG Test"

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem is that after installing TESTNG successfully through Eclipse Marketplace...it is not visible in WINDOWS->SHOW VIEW->OTHER->JAVA->......TESTNG is not there. it might be a compatability issue but i am not sure

Comment: @meenakshi That means TestNG wasn't installed successfully. Which version of Eclipse are you using? Did you get any error while installing TestNG ?

Comment: i am using Eclipse Neon and i did not get any error while installing. infact if  i try to install it again through eclise marketplace...it shows me installed

Comment: @meenakshi Did you perform step number 3 as mentioned in my answer?